# New to Python: Creating a dictionary using two lists, with one of the lists having more than one line

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Without importing any modules, I want to make a dictionary comparing two lists with similar elements, with one of the list containing an extra element each (a description) and want to create a dictionary of the elements in List_A as the key and the 2nd element in List_B as the value if the script finds the elements to be the same.

Example:
List_A = [a,b,c,d,e]
List B = [[b,w], [d,x], [c,y], [a,z]

new_dict = {"a:z", "b:w", "c:y" "d:x"}

Comment: What have you tried? This should be relatively simple using a nested for-loop and an if-statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
def func(l1, l2):
 result = {}
 for a in l1:
  for b in l2:
   if a == b[0]:
    result[a] = b[1]
 return result
```

This works properly when list_A doesn't have any duplicates

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. I tried out the code but the b[1] in that if statement is appending new_dict = {"a:w", "b:w", "c:w" .... - which is the b[1]
Do i need to split the list of b somewhere before indexing [1]?

Comment: I don't think so. It should return a new dictionary. Does it give you an error of some like that?

Comment: Oh my mistake, there was an error in my list_b where all the descriptions were the same

Answer (score 0):

This is effectively a filtering problem. You want to build a dictionary using elements from list_b if and only if the first element exists in list_a. You can achieve that a couple of ways.

```
list_a = [a,b,c,d,e]
list_b = [[b,w], [d,x], [c,y], [a,z]]

result = {}

for pair in list_b:
    if pair[0] in list_a:
        result[pair[0]] = pair[1]
```

Note that you can achieve a similar result with dictionary comprehension:

```
result = {pair[0]:pair[1] for pair in list_b if pair[0] in list_a}
```

I would say though that it might be helpful to revise how you generate the data for list_b, and set it up as a dictionary of items -> descriptions from the get go.